# Android phone gap app restarts on image upload from camera

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, phonegap-build, android-camera-intent

This is my code

```
   package com.sp.spandroid;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
    import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    import java.io.File;

    public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
    {
        private JSBridge jsBridge;
       // public static Activity activity;
        public static ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.init();
          //  activity = this;
            // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
            LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/onCreate==>","onCreate !!");
            jsBridge = new JSBridge(this, super.appView);
            super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(jsBridge, "jsBridge");
            super.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            super.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            super.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
                super.appView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
            }

            loadUrl(launchUrl);
            CordovaInterface cdv = (CordovaInterface)getContext();
            super.appView.setWebChromeClient(new CordovaChromeClient(cdv,super.appView) {
                // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

                    CordovaApp.mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/openFileChooser==>","acceptType ==>"+ acceptType);
                    try {


                        File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                , "sp");

                        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

                        if(acceptType.equals("video/*")){
                            LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/openFileChooser==>","inside video ==>"+ acceptType);
                            i.setType("video/*");
                            File file = new File(
                                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "VIDEO_"
                                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                            + ".3gp");
                            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                    MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser");

                            // Set camera intent to file chooser
                            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
                            LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/openFileChooser==>","openFileChooser 11 !!");
                            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                        }else {
                            // Create camera captured image file path and name
                            File file = new File(
                                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                            + ".jpg");

                            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            // Camera capture image intent
                            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                            i.setType("image/*");
                            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser");

                            // Set camera intent to file chooser
                            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
                            LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/openFileChooser==>","openFileChooser 11 !!");
                            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                        }
                        // Create file chooser intent




                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                // For Android < 3.0
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                    openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
                }

                // For Android  > 4.1.1
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                    openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
                }


                public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                    onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                    return true;
                }

                public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                    Log.d("SPANDROID", "SPANDROID: " + message);
                }
            });

        }




        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/onActivityResult==>","resultCode ==>"+resultCode);
            LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/onActivityResult==>","mUploadMessage ==>"+ CordovaApp.mUploadMessage);
           // LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/onActivityResult==>","intent.getData() ==>"+intent.getData());
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(requestCode==CordovaChromeClient.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {

                if (null ==  CordovaApp.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                Uri result=null;

                try{
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        CordovaApp.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                        return;
                    } else {

                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                LOG.d("SPANDROID/CordovaApp/onActivityResult==>","result ==>"+result);
                CordovaApp.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                CordovaApp.mUploadMessage = null;

            }
        }

    }
```

onActivityResult it is gettting CordovaApp.mUploadMessage as null. App is restarting when i choose an image from camera and i am not able to upload the image. This is happening for some phones only. Phones like moto-e moto-g are showing upload issues